# Как лучше построить график на Android?

Tags: android

Как лучше построить график на Android стандартными средствами, без применения библиотек?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы использовал расширение от drawable
его можно прикрепить к любому view элементу
view.setBackground() или view.setBackgroundDrawable() - для старых ip

```
public class CustomDrawable extends Drawable {
int color1;
int color2;

paint mPaint;

//Переопределить draw
    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        //внутри метода draw рисуем что хочется.

        mPaint.setColor(color1);      
        canvas.drawRect();
        mPaint.setColor(color2);
        canvas.drawOval();
        canvas.drawLine();
        canvas.drawPoint();
    }
}
```

методы которые поддерживат canvas - можно посмотреть тут:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html

Answer (score 0):

Лучше , конечно , воспользоваться готовой библиотекой , ибо это избавит вас от всевозможной рутины , вроде масштабирования координат , чтобы входило в экран , разных математических преобразований и прочей скукоты.

Сама тема рисования под андроид довольно обширна , чтобы уместь ее в такое маленькое окошко целиком .
Коротко : есть  переопределение метода onDraw() , класс [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) и стопка его методов вроде .draw*  . Дальше все в ваших руках - у вас есть точки , линии , круги , овалы , прямоугольники , цвета , трансформируемый текст и проч. необходимое , осалось только добавить кучу математики , чтоб все это совместить и уместить и готово !!
Для подробностей смотрите [этот урок](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/312-urok-142-risovanie-prostye-figury-tekst.html) ( и следующие прям до №156 )